# Simulate ternary operator in Elixir

Tags: elixir, conditional-operator

How to do the similar conditional one-line check in Elixir?

```elixir
if (x > 0) ? x : nil
```

Is this the only equivalent in elixir world?

```elixir
if true, do: 1, else: 2
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To me, the if *IS* the equivalent of a  ternary operator as it evaluates to a value which for various other languages it doesn't.

so  `x = if false, do: 1, else: 2`

is basically `x = false? 1 : 2`

Not sure why Ruby adopted it ( if you are coming from Ruby ) as it has assignable if statements.  in C the ternary is useful as the code bloats with the equivalent if statements.  Of course C programmers desperate for terseness went nuts and did many nested upon nested ternaries  :)

Answer (score 38):

Yes, there's nothing like a ternary operator in Elixir. The keyword version of `if` is probably the closest thing:

```elixir
if condition, do: true_expr, else: false_expr
```

Answer (score 23):

I saw this alternative in an [tweet](https://twitter.com/elixirtip/status/573230242677960704),

```elixir
is_it_true && "TRUE" || "FALSE"
```

Comment: Note that this has a major gotcha: `is_it_true && false || :foobar` will always return `:foobar` and never `false`. This is because `x && false` will always evaluate to a falsy value, for any value of `x` – and `false || x` will always evaluate to `x`, for any value of `x`. The same gotcha applies if you have `nil` instead of `false`.

Comment: `a = true && 1 || 2`, I don't see the gotcha here if you structure it well.

Comment: `a = argument_received && argument || default_value`  If you did receive the argument, but it happens to be a falsie, your program will ignore it, and that's probably not what you want, so... definitively there is a gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

An unmentioned and more verbose alternative is

```elixir
case condition do true -> true_expr; _ -> false_expr end
```

Comment: That will get formatted to use 4 lines and lose truthiness/falseness

Answer (score 2):

```
def ternary(condition, true_val, false_val) do
  if(condition, do: true_val, else: false_val)
end
```

so then

```
ternary(a < b, :ok, :error)
```

Comment: Nice, this looks much easier to read.